# Не отображаются команды своего расширения в VS 2022

Tags: c#, visual-studio-extensions, visual-studio-2022

Создаю проект с созданием расширения и добавляю команду но в версии VS для тестирования созданного расширения ничего не появляется. Создавал и готовый и пустой проект. Делал все по документации на сайте. Не могу понять что я делаю не так.

Comment: _Вопросы с просьбами помочь с отладкой («почему этот код не работает?») должны включать желаемое поведение, конкретную проблему или ошибку и минимальный код для её воспроизведения прямо в вопросе._

Comment: Там почти и нету кода, по документации https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/visualstudio/extensibility/extensibility-hello-world?view=vs-2022 делаю тоже самое и не появляются команды

Comment: И нету никаких ошибок как будто просто ничего не происходит